# Combine two dataframes with structs in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes (**A** and **B**) with the following schema

```
 root
     |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Books: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true) 
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

What is the best and the cleaning way to combine the two dataframes and each item will be as a struct field in a new colmun, to get that as a result :

```
+---------+-------- +------------
|AUTHOR_ID| A       + B          |     
+---------+-------- + -----------|
|  1      | {}      |   {}       |   keep the nested structs in the new column
|         |         |            |
```

Comment: Maybe there a pyspark function that let us to so without doing `joins` ?

Comment: `join` won't lose the schema but do you need to join with `AUTHOR_ID` AND `BOOK_ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the best way is to add some new columns with one simple `join`

- Note: we suppose that the 2 dataframes **df_A** and **df_B** have the same schema

  ```
    columns = df_A.columns

    b_ = df_B.withColumnRenamed('AUTHOR_ID', 'ref_id')          # to retain null fields when no item match
    return df_A.withColumn('A', f.struct(columns))\
            .select('AUTHOR_ID', 'A')\
            .join(b_, df_A['AUTHOR_ID'] == b_.ref_id, 'left')\
            .withColumn('B', f.when(f.col('ref_id').isNotNull(), f.struct(*[columns])).otherwise(f.lit(None)))\
            .select('AUTHOR_ID', 'A', 'B')
  ```